# fill data dynamically in a combo box in Userform

Tags: vba, checkbox, combobox, userform

I'm still learning about VBA programming and I need to know how to fill data dynamically in a combo box when checking many checkpoints without a specific order.

Thank you so much for your help !

The image that I attached to this message describes the situation. Actually I would like to when checking for example the boxes "a" and "c" list in the comboboxes the list of data that refer to a and c.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97j9H.jpg)

Comment: Try some code out first - post here (with your code) if you run into problems.  This is not really a good place for a "please show me how" question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any code at least we need a little more information:

What kind of information shall be filled into the comboboxes if either of the checkboxes is selected? And especially: you have 3 (or 4) comboboxes, what has to be filled in where??

Maybe like this we can at least give you a hint how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I developed so far

[image: image of code developed]